# How to configure a query timeout in Neo4j 3.0.1

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to set a query timeout in `neo4j.conf` for Neo4j 3.0.1. Any query taking longer than the timeout should get killed. I'm primarily concerned with setting the timeout for queries originating from the Neo4j Browser.

It looks like [this was possible](https://dzone.com/articles/10-caveats-neo4j-users-should) in the past with:

```
execution_guard_enabled=true
org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime=20000
```

However, this old method doesn't work for me. I see Neo4j 3.0 has a [`dbms.transaction_timeout`](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/#config_dbms.transaction_timeout) option defined as a "timeout for idle transactions". However, this setting also doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Try `unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.enabled=true; unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.time=20000`.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [**@stdob**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989460/stdob) for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400476/how-to-configure-a-query-timeout-in-neo4j-3-0-1?noredirect=1#comment62320600_374004760) explaining a solution.

In Neo4j 3.0.1 Community, I verified that the following addition to `neo4j.conf` enabled a query timeout of 1 second for Browser queries:

```
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.enabled=true
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.time=1s
```

I did not check whether the timeout applies to queries oustide of Neo4j Browser, but I assume so. I did find some documentation in the Neo4j codebase for [`unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.time`](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/6280974efc9b082d5f40044df362355134a8632b/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/configuration/ServerSettings.java#L129):

> If execution time limiting is enabled in the database, this configures the maximum request execution time.

Answer (score 4):

I believe `dbms.transaction.timeout` is the current way of limiting execution time