# Increase timeout time in React - neo4j app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, neo4j, axios

I am trying to increase the timeout time of my `React` app. I am using `axios`, so initially I tried:

```
axios.post('/gene_info', postData, {timeout: timeoutVal});
```

It did not work, and there is the respective thread that deals with it:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/647

So, I tried the following code:

```
 let CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
      const source = CancelToken.source();
      try {
          let response = null;
          setTimeout(() => {
              if (response === null) {
                  source.cancel();
              }
          }, 60 * 1500 * 1000);

          response = await axios.post('/gene_info', postData, {cancelToken: source.token});
          console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
```

And it is not working either. The request times out and I see the empty response error, even though on the `Node.js` backend I see that the result is returned correctly. On the backend I am making a very long running request to `Neo4j` database. I got a suspicion that maybe it timeouts, so I added to `neo4j.config` file the following lines:

```
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.enabled=true
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.time=99999999999999s
```

That I found here:

[How to configure a query timeout in Neo4j 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400476/how-to-configure-a-query-timeout-in-neo4j-3-0-1)

and restarted `neo4j` but it did not help either. Here is what I see in the terminal:

[image]

I am not sure what this `POST /gene_info - - ms - -` means, whether the problem is still on the front end, or the back end, but I have a suspicion that `neo4j` now times out, but it is still calculating the result which I see using `console.log()` statements. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried using `Reacts` `fetch`, but still not working. Here is the code:

```
fetchWithTimeout = (url, postData, timeout) => {
let didTimeOut = false;

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        didTimeOut = true;
        reject(new Error('Request timed out'));
    }, timeout);

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        timeout: timeout,
        body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        // Clear the timeout as cleanup
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if(!didTimeOut) {
            console.log('fetch good! ', response);
            resolve(response);
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('fetch failed! ', err);

        // Rejection already happened with setTimeout
        if(didTimeOut) return;
        // Reject with error
        reject(err);
    });
})
.then(function() {
    // Request success and no timeout
    console.log('good promise, no timeout! ');
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // Error: response error, request timeout or runtime error
    console.log('promise error! ', err);
});
}
```

Then I am calling this function like that:

```
let postData = {"jsonData": geneNameArr,
                    "datasetName": this.props.datasetName};
this.fetchWithTimeout('/gene_info', postData, timeout).then((response) => {
        console.log("fetchWithTimeout is done!");
        console.log(response);
      });
```

> Update

I tried using `axios.create()` function with no success:

```
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: '/gene_info',
        timeout: timeout
    });

    axiosInstance.post('', postData).then((response) => {
      console.log("axios request is done with create() method");
      console.log(response);
    });
```

If nothing seems to work on the front end, I would think it is the timeout that comes from the `neo4j` driver, even though somehow the results are returned. Here is the code I am using for the driver:

```
router.post('/gene_info', function(req, res) {
...
...
var driver = dbUtils.driver;
const session = driver.session();
session.run(
  full_query,
  {}
 ).then(result => {
  const exprData = chartService.prepareGeneInfoData(result, '');
  res.json({
    exprData
  });

  session.close();
});
})
```

Or maybe it can also be `express.Router();` that I am using for treating `get` and `post` requests on the backend with `Node.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I found the solution that worked here:

[Node Express specific timeout value per route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882237/node-express-specific-timeout-value-per-route)

And I used the `setConnectionTimeout()` function in the following way:

```
router.post('/gene_info', setConnectionTimeout('12h'), function(req, res) {
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to configure your timeout in axios, you can use,

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://example.com/api/",
    timeout: 5000
});
```

Replace `5000` with your timeout value needed.

Comment: No, it did not help either, and the timeout keeps happening. I updated the question with the code with `axios.create()` that I used.

Comment: Did you set your time out like, `timeout: timeout`? or with value for second timeout? And you can confirm whether this is a client side issue by using postman. Send the request using postman, if that too fails it might be an issue with server side not `send`ing the response.